# How to send images via sockets

Tags: java, sockets, tcpclient

I am trying to make a server-client model in which the server can see what the client is doing on their systems. I want to capture and send an image via a socket (skt). How can I display the image received by the server.

Client Thread:

```
screenShot = new Robot().createScreenCapture(new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize()));
                    ImageIO.write(screenShot, "PNG", skt.getOutputStream());
```

Server Thread:

```
                BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(connarray.get(0).getInputStream());
                Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
                g.drawImage(image, 500, 500, null);
```

Comment: I am making this program as a GUI in netbeans.

Comment: I don't actually see what you're asking... Is something happening that you need help with? Are you getting an error? This question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't ask an actual question here, but I could make a couple of observations.

1. Both your client and server code is catching and **squashing** exceptions.  If any exceptions were thrown by the client or server-side, your code is throwing away all of the evidence.  Change

   ```
       } catch(Exception ew) { }
   ```

   to

   ```
       } catch(Exception ew) { ew.printStackTrace(); }
   ```

   If there are exceptions being thrown, this will tell you what they are.  (In production code, you should probably log exceptions instead of calling `printStackTrace(...)` ... but that is a lesson for later.)
2. Taking a screenshot every 1/10th of a second is going to generate a lot of load on the client and server side.
3. There are existing (non-Java) tools for doing this kind of thing.

Comment: Actually i am not able to display the received image on the server side. Can you please give me detailed code and explanation on  how to display the received image in a label or something like that.